# How to handle an interrupted in-app purchase with specific data

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I want to set up a consumable in-app purchase that buys a virtual ticket for a specific event in my app. When they buy the ticket I will send a message to my server to add their userID for a specific event ID in the database. There will be many events that a user could buy a consumable ticket for.

I am aware of the necessity for a `SKPaymentTransactionObserver` subclass which handles transactions.

However, if something goes wrong (they background the app, battery dies, loss of internet connection) the `SKPaymentTransactionObserver` will be sent the transaction until I call `-finishTransaction`. How can I know what event ID they've purchased the consumable for in this instance? Is there a payload that I can attach to a transaction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no official way to add a payload to a payment request. If you provide a consumable for each event, you can check for the product id, but I assume it would be overkill to provide and maintain a consumable for each possible event.

You could try to abuse the `applicationUsername` field for that. But, corresponding to Apple's documentation (see below) and the fact it isn't guaranteed to be persisted, I wouldn't recommend that.

> The applicationUsername property is not guaranteed to persist between when you add the payment transaction to the queue and when the queue updates the transaction. Do not attempt to use this property for purposes other than providing fraud detection.

Another way could be to remember each created transaction mapped to its event id in a dictionary and after a transaction succeeded, you look into that dictionary for the corresponding event id. This works as long as the app doesn't restart. You could also remember the mapping between transactions and event ids within the user defaults.

Comment: I think using userdefaults is probably the best way for me to do this - or to save it to the server db before creating the transaction, but that could be over kill. Then when I call `-finishTransaction` I can remove it from the defaults.

Comment: The safest would be to use a cross-device solution, because otherwise it could happen that a user handles the transaction on a different device than the one he initiated the purchase with. For that you could use iCloud Key-Value Storage. But, since you are communicating with your server anyways, I would propose you use your server, because then you can prevent a user from accidentally redeeming a purchase twice (your server can evaluate if a transaction was already redeemed).

Comment: Ah, I didn't realise they could complete a transaction on a different device. Thanks

Comment: Although actually, if they're consumable transactions, they're not synced across devices are they?

Comment: I am not quite sure if this also applies for consumable

Comment: Probably they will only be send to the purchasing device

Comment: Problem here, there's no transactionId defined until AFTER the transaction has completed. Is there any other way to uniquely identify a transaction before it is purchased? It could be interrupted while purchasing surely?

Comment: Referring to your initial question (app goes into the background, no internet, ...), waiting till then could be too late. But, you could use the `SKPaymentTransaction` itself as key.

Comment: If the app was force quit some how and when they opened it it retried it, the new SKPaymentTransaction that it creates wouldn't be recognised as the key though would it?

Comment: Since we do not persist the transactions, I can't tell you for sure, but we also rely on transactions as a keys, and it has worked well so far. The transaction we received in `paymentQueue(_:updatedTransactions:)` was always the same, as we used to trigger the purchase in the beginning with. I can't imagine the behavior changes just because the app was restarted

Comment: Just tried this, it doesn't let you persist the transaction in userdefaults

Comment: @Tometoyou did you find solution for this? This is also my problem.